# Displaying cds data in powerapps portal

Tags: html-table, powerapps, portal, common-data-service, powerapps-portal

I was trying to display cds data in powerapps portal web page

This is the code i used

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0goJN.png)

Total record size was displaying but the table is empty

here is output screenshot

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETLUY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the table permissions for the custom entity you are fetching.

In portal management

1. Under security > Table Permissions
2. Create new > Choose your table
3. Add appropriate permissions
4. Hit Save and Close

In Portal studio

1. Pres sync configuration and browse the website. And press "Ctrl+F5"

Hope it helps.